# CSS - Flex grid that resizes items to stay within container constraints

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need some assistance with a flexbox "grid". The goal is to fit multiple items in the flex container and have the items resize themselves to fit the dimensions of the container. Currently it works wells for 2 items but when the 3rd is added it gets appended to a new row as expected but the items dont resize themselves but end up expanding the container.

The items are added in js to the container.

HTML

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    height: 90vh;
}

.flex-main-view {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 100%;
    background-color: red;
    min-height: 0;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.flex-video-container {
    display: flex;
    margin: 16px;
    /*flex: 1 1 auto;*/
}

    .flex-video-container video {
        display: flex;
        border-radius: 10px !important;
    }


.flex-side-view {
    display: none;
    flex: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container"><div id="flex-participants" class="flex-main-view"><div class="flex-video-container"><video autoplay="" playsinline=""></video></div><div id="d2ce6d09-0c54-41bb-8e04-a4366c1e0b8a" class="flex-video-container"><video autoplay="" playsinline="" id="MT1247ef977dca85d5a9345b7698a6c672"></video></div><audio autoplay="" id="MTf8b9a2ac84d609b76bedab6fd587c541"></audio><audio autoplay="" id="MTcf170906978f53fdc389a2bec23a8510"></audio><div id="5f4b5763-d609-4401-9bc6-f0a34a3ad734" class="flex-video-container"><video autoplay="" playsinline="" id="MTa499d4574e348db5160cccdb83e80be9"></video></div></div>
    <div class="flex-side-view"></div></div>
```

Comment: Here is a screenshot of what it looks like with active video [link](https://imgur.com/MEUoHt1)

Comment: The code posted in your question doesn't reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this is the result you expect. I've added `flex: 0 1 auto;` to the `.flex-video-container video`. (Also made the video background white just to be able to see them)

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    height: 90vh;
}

.flex-main-view {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 100%;
    background-color: skyblue;
    min-height: 0;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.flex-video-container {
    display: flex;
    margin: 16px;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
}

    .flex-video-container video {
        display: flex;
        flex: 1 1 auto;
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 10px !important;
    }


.flex-side-view {
    display: none;
    flex: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div id="flex-participants" class="flex-main-view">
    <div class="flex-video-container">
      <video autoplay="" playsinline=""></video>
    </div>
    <div id="d2ce6d09-0c54-41bb-8e04-a4366c1e0b8a" class="flex-video-container">
      <video autoplay="" playsinline="" id="MT1247ef977dca85d5a9345b7698a6c672"></video>
    </div>
    <audio autoplay="" id="MTf8b9a2ac84d609b76bedab6fd587c541"></audio>
    <audio autoplay="" id="MTcf170906978f53fdc389a2bec23a8510"></audio>
    <div id="5f4b5763-d609-4401-9bc6-f0a34a3ad734" class="flex-video-container">
      <video autoplay="" playsinline="" id="MTa499d4574e348db5160cccdb83e80be9"></video>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-side-view"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: it works well for 3 elements, but when I bump it up to 6 elements, the 6th one is quite large. How can I restrict its size?

Comment: I've changed the snippet a bit. Check it now. I've changed the flex property on the `.flex-video-container` to `flex: 0 1 auto;` The first number is short for `flex-grow`, the second is short for `flex-shrink`. You need to restrict the div not to grow and expand to full width. The third value is for the `flex-basis`, which determines the element(s) width that they could take